# web scrapping Proplem no such element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to make web scrapping using Selenium, I have an issue with the below message,
this issue related to no such element as what it mean ?

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"a[1]/div[1]/img"}
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.149); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

and also I searched more and more and didn't solve it, can anyone help me?
as I did more modification in my code but same issue still exist
here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time as t
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


import urllib
import cv2
import os

try:
    os.mkdir("G:/Smokking_Project")    
except:
    pass




name="smoked"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  

strr="https://www.google.com/search?q=smokinng&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi8k9zn9eOBAxVtlycCHTa_DnUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=smokinng&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIJCAAQGBCABBAKMgkIABAYEIAEEAoyCQgAEBgQgAQQCjoECCMQJzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAUQHjoECAAQHjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BAgAEAM6BwgAEBgQgARQjwdY8xJg-RloAHAAeACAAb0BiAHsCZIBAzAuOZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=uUwhZfzSFO2unsEPtv66qAc&bih=723&biw=1517&hl=en"

driver.get(strr)
t.sleep(3)


pics= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]')
links=[]
x=1
last_height=0

def download_image(url,filename):
    resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    output = open(filename,"wb")
    output.write(resource.read())
    output.close()
    
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    t.sleep(4)
    pics_ =pics.find_elements(By.XPATH,'./*') 
  
 
    for pic in pics_:
        #try:
            #img_link=pic.find_element_by_xpath('a[1]/div[1]/img').get_attribute('src') 
            #img_link=pic.find_element_by_xpath('a[1]/div[1]/img').get_attribute('src')
            img_link= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'a[1]/div[1]/img').get_attribute('src') 
         
            if img_link not in links:
                links.append(img_link)

                try:
                    os.mkdir('G://Smokking_Project//'+name)
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    os.mkdir('G://Smokking_Project//'+name)
                except:
                    pass
                file_name='Smokking_Project//'+name+'//'+str(x)+'.jpg'
                download_image(img_link,file_name)
                
                x+=1
        #except:
          #  print('-',end='')
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print(new_height)
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
        
        
driver.close()
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should locate the images:

```
[..]
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t 
[..]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=smokinng&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi8k9zn9eOBAxVtlycCHTa_DnUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=smokinng&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIJCAAQGBCABBAKMgkIABAYEIAEEAoyCQgAEBgQgAQQCjoECCMQJzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAUQHjoECAAQHjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BAgAEAM6BwgAEBgQgARQjwdY8xJg-RloAHAAeACAAb0BiAHsCZIBAzAuOZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=uUwhZfzSFO2unsEPtv66qAc&bih=723&biw=1517&hl=en'
driver.get(url)
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    img_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//a[1]/div[1]/img')))
    t.sleep(1)
    for img in img_links:
      print(img.get_attribute('src'))  
### do whatever you want with this data, I'm printing it for demo purposes
### also make sure you have some condition to break out of this infinite loop
```

This will return all `src` for images in page: some will be base64 strings, some will be urls.

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: thanks for your comment your solution solves my issue but I have another issue when I try to download the image  it contains base 65 and URLs  how can i deal with them in the function download_image as it gives me a list has no attribute time out

Comment: Base64 image codes can be decoded into actual images, and those images saved to disk, along with other images downloaded from their urls, if that's what you're after. In any case, that's another question on it's own.

Comment: @PeterSmith  could you please update code and show me how to download base64 and image from URL as I found URL and base64

Comment: could you help me ?